# My ObjectSet filter doesn't get translated into SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

I have written this filter to get only documents that match certain periods of time from the database :

The *Period* entity is straightforward and contains two properties : **DateFrom** and **DateTo**.

I need to build a filter from lambdas, each one for each *Period* that is submitted to build the filter.

The filter, when is completely built, has to look like this :

```
ObjectSet.Where(d => 
    (d.Date >= Period1.DateFrom && d.Date <= Period1.DateTo)
    || (d.Date >= Period2.DateFrom && d.Date <= Period2.DateTo)
    || (d.Date >= Period3.DateFrom && d.Date <= Period3.DateTo));
```

As you can guess, I have to **dynamically** build this filter because **the number of submitted *periods* to build the filter can vary.**

*(The following is the `Expression` I use to combine the lambdas (each one for each period of time that have been submitted to build the filter)*

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> CombineWithOr<T>(
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> firstExpression, 
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> secondExpression)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

    var resultBody = Expression.Or(
        Expression.Invoke(firstExpression, parameter), 
        Expression.Invoke(secondExpression, parameter));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(resultBody, parameter);
}
```

Here is where I combine each lambda for each period there is to add to the document filter :

```
public IList<Document> GetDocuments(IList<Periods> periods)
{
    Expression<Func<Document, bool>> resultExpression = n => false;

    foreach (var submittedPeriod in periods)
    {
        var period = submittedPeriod;
        Expression<Func<Document, bool>> expression =
            d => (d.Date >= period.DateFrom && d.Date <= period.DateTo);
        resultExpression = this.CombineWithOr(resultExpression, expression);
    }

    var query = this.ObjectSet.Where(resultExpression.Compile());
}
```

The problem is, when I launch deferred execution of the query  ...

```
var documents = query.ToList();
```

... and I look at the resulting SQL, **nothing is added** to the SELECT statement.

---

If I execute the query without compiling the resulting Expression like this :

```
var query = this.ObjectSet.Where(resultExpression);
```

I get this exception :

> The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities.

That means that the Linq-To-Entities query provider doesn't know how to translate my filter into SQL code.

What is bugging me right now is how such a simple DateTime comparison from entities (*Document* and *Period*) that are both part of my Entity schema can mess up the provider ?

Any ideas how I can achieve such a filtering ?

Comment: Have you tried `this.ObjectSet.Where(resultExpression)` instead?

Comment: @svick : If I don't compile resultExpression, I get this exception : _The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities._

Comment: @JoanLeaven That means you're actually using the query provider for the first time and not just doing the whole thing in linq to objects.  Now you need to figure out how to create a query that the query provider knows how to translate.

Comment: @JoanLeaven It's not the individual conditional expressions that it doesn't know how to translate, it's your means of combining them is creating a complex construct that it doesn't know how to parse.

Comment: @Servy : That is the only way I have found to dynamically combine my predicates. Do you know of a simpler or better way ?

Comment: @JoanLeaven Not really, I'm just telling you where the problem is so you don't spend time changing other sections that aren't a problem.

Comment: @Servy : Thanks for your input. I will keep searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `.AsExpandable()` before the query. More information is [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx)

Comment: Note that I want to acheive this without using the LinqKit Library.

`ObjectSet` doesn't have such a method available. It has, however, `ToExpandable()`, which I tried like this :
`var query = this.ObjectSet.ToExpandable().Where(resultExpression);`

I get the same Exception : _The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities._

Comment: @JoanLeaven Why do you want to do this without LinqKit? This is exactly what LinqKit was made for.

Comment: @svick : I just cannot believe that what I want to do is impossible using only Expressions out-of-the-box. Our current project has dependancies on a library that acts like LinqKit :it's from an individual or company called EekSoft. My goal is to remove that from the project. It's kinda obscure and generates rubbish and so malformed SQL code that it takes forever to execute on the server.

Comment: @JoanLeaven It's not impossible, but it's not trivial either. Basically, it would mean you would have to reimplement LinqKit. And I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: @svick. I see. I'm not a fan of reinventing the wheel either. I'm just really traumatized by EekSoft and how it has poisoned our data access layer with simple linq queries that are translated into an average of 150 kilobytes queries and that it has been a real pain in the ass to work with. I guess I should give LinqKit a try. Thanks.

Comment: @svick Since you've been very participative and suggested a good solution, you can write an answer explaining about the LinqKit solution and I will mark it as an answer. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I ended up using LinqKit which translates my dynamic filter to SQL code very efficiently. Thanks to you all for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your combining function. SQL to Entities doesn't really like Invoke. Here's a combining function that worked for me:

```
public static class ExpressionCombiner
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> a, Expression<Func<T, bool>> b)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var substituter = new SubstituteParameter(parameter, p => true);

        var resultBody = Expression.Or(
            substituter.Visit(a.Body),
            substituter.Visit(b.Body));

        Expression<Func<T, bool>> combined = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(resultBody, parameter);
        return combined;
    }
}

public class SubstituteParameter : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression toReplace;
    private Func<ParameterExpression, bool> isReplacementRequiredFunc;
    public SubstituteParameter(ParameterExpression toReplace, Func<ParameterExpression, bool> isReplacementRequiredFunc)
    {
        this.toReplace = toReplace;
        this.isReplacementRequiredFunc = isReplacementRequiredFunc;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return isReplacementRequiredFunc(node) ? toReplace : node;
    }
}
```